# "else" function coming up as invalid syntax in my loop

Tags: python, spyder

```
#This program is supposed to act as a Magic 8 Ball and choosing a hand of five cards out of a deck of cards

# All the possible Magic 8 Ball responses
response = ["As I see it, yes", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", "It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Most likely", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Outlook good", "Reply hazy, try again", "Signs point to yes", "Very doubtful", "Without a doubt", "Yes", "Yes - definitely", "You may rely on it"]

#All the possible cards to choose from in a deck of cards
deck = ["ACE OF CLUBS", "2 OF CLUBS", "3 OF CLUBS", "4 OF CLUBS", "5 OF CLUBS", "6 OF CLUBS", "7 OF CLUBS", "8 OF CLUBS", "9 OF CLUBS", "10 OF CLUBS", "JACK OF CLUBS", "QUEEN OF CLUBS", "KING OF CLUBS", "ACE OF SPADES", "2 OF SPADES", "3 OF SPADES", "4 OF SPADES", "5 OF SPADES", "6 OF SPADES", "7 OF SPADES", "8 OF SPADES", "9 OF SPADES", "10 OF SPADES", "JACK OF SPADES", "QUEEN OF SPADES", "KING OF SPADES", "ACE OF HEARTS", "2 OF HEARTS", "3 OF HEARTS", "4 OF HEARTS", "5 OF HEARTS", "6 OF HEARTS", "7 OF HEARTS", "8 OF HEARTS", "9 OF HEARTS", "10 OF HEARTS", "JACK OF HEARTS", "QUEEN OF HEARTS", "KING OF HEARTS", "ACE OF DIAMONDS", "2 OF DIAMONDS", "3 OF DIAMONDS", "4 OF DIAMONDS", "5 OF DIAMONDS", "6 OF DIAMONDS", "7 OF DIAMONDS", "8 OF DIAMONDS", "9 OF DIAMONDS", "10 OF DIAMONDS", "JACK OF DIAMONDS", "QUEEN OF DIAMONDS", "KING OF DIAMONDS"]

import math

#Constants
N = 10000 # The norm
A = 4875  # The adder
M = 8601  # The multiplier

K = 1

C = 5
# -----------------------------------------
# The pseudorandom number generator

keep_going = 'Y'
keep_going_II = 'Y'

if keep_going == 'Y':
    while keep_going in ['y', 'Y']: #Allows user to input either a lowercase or uppercase 'Y' when asked if they want to ask another question
        X = input("Enter a YES or NO question: ")
        S = int(input("Now enter an integer: "))
        for i in range(K):
            S = (S * M + A) % N # Random Number Generator
            r = S/N #On the interval [0,1)
            magic = math.floor(20 * r)
            print("The Magic 8 Ball says:", response[magic]) 

            #Asking the user if they want to ask another question
            keep_going = input('Do you want to ask another question ' +
                               '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')

#Now asking the user if they would like to draw a hand of five cards    
keep_going_II = input('Would you like to draw a hand of five cards ' +
                      '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')

else:
    while keep_going_II in ['y', 'Y']:
        S = int(input("Enter the current time in the 24 hour mode: "))
        for a in range(C):
            S = (S * M + A) % N
            r = S/N
            card = math.floor(52 * r)
            print("Your hand that was chosen is:")
            print(deck[card])

            keep_going_II = input('Would you like to draw another hand ' +
                                  '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
```

So the way I want my program to work is to first act like a Magic 8 Ball. If they input "Y", then the Magic 8 Ball loops again. But if the user inputs "N", the program would then ask if the user would like to draw a hand of 5 cards from the possible 52 options. But as the title says, the programming is treating the "else" as invalid syntax. Any idea what I did wrong? I also think I may have assigned my variables wrong or something.

Comment: The line beginning with `keep_going_II =` ends the `if` statement, so your `else:` statement doesn't have an `if` to go with it.[

Comment: Watch your indention - `keep_going_II` breaks the `if/else` construct.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the assignment of `keep_going_II` inside the `else:` block. Otherwise, it breaks the connection between `if` and `else`.

```
if keep_going == 'Y':
    while keep_going in ['y', 'Y']: #Allows user to input either a lowercase or uppercase 'Y' when asked if they want to ask another question
        X = input("Enter a YES or NO question: ")
        S = int(input("Now enter an integer: "))
        for i in range(K):
            S = (S * M + A) % N # Random Number Generator
            r = S/N #On the interval [0,1)
            magic = math.floor(20 * r)
            print("The Magic 8 Ball says:", response[magic]) 

            #Asking the user if they want to ask another question
            keep_going = input('Do you want to ask another question ' +
                               '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
else:
    #Now asking the user if they would like to draw a hand of five cards    
    keep_going_II = input('Would you like to draw a hand of five cards ' +
                          '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
    while keep_going_II in ['y', 'Y']:
        S = int(input("Enter the current time in the 24 hour mode: "))
        for a in range(C):
            S = (S * M + A) % N
            r = S/N
            card = math.floor(52 * r)
            print("Your hand that was chosen is:")
            print(deck[card])

            keep_going_II = input('Would you like to draw another hand ' +
                                  '(Enter Y for yes and N for no): ')
```

Comment: Hmmm, I switched the line of where the assignment `keep_going_II`, but now the overall `else:` statement doesn't seem to be working once the user inputs "N" to end the Magic 8 Ball loop.

Comment: This `if` and `else` only runs once when the program starts, not every time through the loop. It's not clear why you even need them.

Comment: The `if` statement is just testing the variable that you assign with `keep_going = 'Y'`, not after the user answers the question in the loop. So it will never go to `else:`.